# When I use RUN yum -y vim in dockerfile, it prompts me /bin/sh: 1: yum: not found ,

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I use RUN yum -y vim in dockerfile, it prompts me /bin/sh: 1: yum: not found , how to deal with this problem?
This is the dockerfile I wrote

```
From centos:7
From openjdk:11
MAINTAINER Dengc


ENV MYPATH /usr/local
WORKDIR $MYPATH
RUN yum -y  install  vim
RUN ynm -y  install  net-tools
RUN yum -y  install  ncuress

EXPOSE 80
CMD /bin/bash
```

After executing docker build -t mycentos .

Answer (score 0):

The openjdk image is not a centos image.

You use `FROM` multiple times, the latest is the image that is used for the commands that follow.

Also, openjdk is officially deprecated, so you should not use it.